# Fast loading and querying data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle, pytables

I am doing some data analysis in Python. I have ~15k financial products identified by ISIN code and ~15 columns of daily data for each of them. I would like to easily and quickly access the data given an ISIN code.

The data is in a MySQL DB. On the Python side so far I have been working with Pandas DataFrame.

First thing I did was to use pd.read_sql to load the DF directly from the database. However, this is relatively slow. Then I tried loading the full database in a single DF and serializing it to a pickle file. The loading of the pickle file is fast, a few seconds. However, when querying for an individual product, the perfomance is the same as if I am querying the SQL DB. Here is some code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, engine
from src.Database import Database
import time
import src.bonds.database.BondDynamicDataETL as BondsETL

database_instance = Database(Database.get_db_instance_risk_analytics_prod())

engine = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://"
    + database_instance.get_db_user()
    + ":"
    + database_instance.get_db_pass()
    + "@"
    + database_instance.get_db_host()
    + "/"
    + database_instance.get_db_name()
)
con = engine.connect()


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
        print("made a DatBase instance")

    def get_individual_bond_dynamic_data(self, isin):
        return self.get_individual_bond_dynamic_data_from_db(isin, con)

    @staticmethod
    def get_individual_bond_dynamic_data_from_db(isin, connection):
        df = pd.read_sql(
            "SELECT * FROM BondDynamicDataClean WHERE isin = '"
            + isin
            + "' ORDER BY date ASC",
            con=connection,
        )
        df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
        return df


class PickleFile:
    def __init__(self):
        print("made a PickleFile instance")
        df = pd.read_pickle("bonds_pickle.pickle")
        # df.set_index(['isin', 'date'], inplace=True)
        self.data = df
        print("loaded file")

    def get_individual_bond_dynamic_data(self, isin):
        result = self.data.query("isin == '@isin'")
        return result


fromPickle = PickleFile()
fromDB = DataBase()

isins = BondsETL.get_all_isins_with_dynamic_data_from_db(
    connection=con,
    table_name=database_instance.get_bonds_dynamic_data_clean_table_name(),
)

isins = isins[0:50]

start_pickle = time.time()

for i, isin in enumerate(isins):
    x = fromPickle.get_individual_bond_dynamic_data(isin)
    print("pickle: " + str(i))

stop_pickle = time.time()

for i, isin in enumerate(isins):
    x = fromDB.get_individual_bond_dynamic_data(isin)
    print("db: " + str(i))

stop_db = time.time()

pickle_t = stop_pickle - start_pickle
db_t = stop_db - stop_pickle
print("pickle: " + str(pickle_t))
print("db: " + str(db_t))
print("ratio: " + str(pickle_t / db_t))
```

This results in:
    pickle: 7.636280059814453
    db: 6.167926073074341
    ratio: 1.23806283819615

Also, curiously enough setting the index on the DF (uncommenting the line in the constructor) slows down everything!

I thought of trying https://www.pytables.org/index.html as an alternative to Pandas. Any other ideas or comments?

Greetings,
Georgi

Comment: There are so many things in your example that are imported from elsewhere (i.e. that are black boxes for us), it's hard to say what is causing the slowdown. Is your database properly indexed for what you're doing, to begin with? (That is, does it have an index on the `isin` column?)

Comment: sorry @AKX. I see what you mean. I think many of the imports are not critical to the problem. The schema itself is simple. The main thing is that if I return just a string instead of **result = self.data.query("isin == '@isin'")**, the "loading" becomes instantaneous. Hence, the bottlenech is in querying the data after it is put into a DataFrame. Does this help?

Comment: Also, you seem to be using `PyMySQL`, which is a pure-Python implementation of a MySQL client, and will definitely be slower than the binary alternatives (`mysqlclient`).

Answer (score 0):

So, collating some thoughts from the comments:

- Use `mysqlclient` instead of PyMySQL if you want more speed on the SQL side of the fence.
- Ensure the columns you're querying on are indexed in your SQL table (`isin` for querying and `date` for ordering).
- You can set `index_col="date"` directly in `read_sql()` [according to the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql); it might be faster.
- I'm no Pandas expert, but I think `self.data[self.data.isin == isin]` would be more performant than `self.data.query("isin == '@isin'")`.
- If you don't need to query things cross-isin and want to use pickles, you could store the data for each isin in a separate pickle file.
- Also, for the sake of Lil Bobby Tables, the patron saint of SQL injection attacks, use parameters in your SQL statements instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: >I'm no Pandas expert, but I think self.data[self.data.isin == isin] would be more performant than self.data.query("isin == '@isin'").
It is the other way around, I have tried it.

Comment: I installed **https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/** via **pip3 install mysqlclient** but not sure how to use it when creating the engine. **mysql+mysqldb** or **mysql+mysqlclient** do not work. And mysqldb is not supported with Python 3+ anyway.

Comment: Just `mysql://` should probably do

Answer (score 0):

It helped a lot to transform the large data frame into a dictionary {isin -> DF} of smaller data frames indexed by ISIN code. Data retrieval is much more efficient from a dictionary compared to from a DF. Also, it is very natural to be able to request a single DF given an ISIN code. Hope this helps someone else.